# Traits as a return value from a function

Tags: traits, rust

I have two enums, `NormalColour` and `BoldColour`, both of which implement the `Colour` trait. They contain `Blue`, `BoldGreen`, and so on.

I'd like to return values of both of these types from the same function, treating them as though they're just a `Colour` value, calling the `paint` function on the result, but I can't find a way to coerce the Rust complier into doing this for me. I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
pub trait Colour {
    fn paint(&self, input: &str) -> String;
}

fn file_colour(stat: &io::FileStat) -> Colour {
    if stat.kind == io::TypeDirectory {
        Blue
    } else if stat.perm & io::UserExecute == io::UserExecute {
        BoldGreen
    } else {
        White
    }
}
```

What type do I have to make the function return for it to work?

I'll eventually like to make more types implement `Colour`, which is why I'm not interested in just turning the two enums into one big enum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is *trait objects*. This means that you will work with `Box<Colour>` as your type; bare `Colour` is not an instantiable type. You can cast `Box<T>` objects to `Box<Colour>` with the `as` operator: `Box::new(NormalColour::White) as Box<Colour>`. In many places this is not necessary (just write `Box::new(NormalColour::White)` and it can be automatically coerced to `Box<Colour>`), but sometimes it will still be necessary.

Still, if you can do it as an enum, that will probably be a nicer solution.

Comment: How does the signature look like?

Comment: @JuanIbiapina: it was a return type of `~Colour` at the time; now, that is `Box<Colour>`. `&'static Colour` would probably work as well, as a matter of fact.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I have a set of object types in my design that could be related through a common trait, and an enum would be almost a tragedy because there would be around 50-75 members in the enum. Also I'd want to return an Option<SomethingLikeTheTrait> for the case where the remote guy misspelled the name. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @cardiffspaceman: lots of members in the enum isn’t a disaster by any means. For the rest of your question, I haven’t got a clue what you mean. And it’s a separate question from this and not appropriate for a comment on an answer of another question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above suggests:

```
fn file_colour(stat: &io::FileStat) -> Box<Colour> { /* ... */ }
```

which works, but you need to wrap all of the returns in a `Box::new()` call.

However, in Rust 1.26 you can now say

```
fn file_colour(stat: &io::FileStat) -> impl Colour { /* ... */ }
```

and simply return the value. No `Box` needed.

Comment: Sometimes. Sometimes you still need a trait object. More detail is in the duplicate.

Comment: Agreed @Shepmaster. Thanks for marking the duplicate.