# Traits as a return value from a function, and explicit cast

Tags: casting, rust, traits

Exactly in the same way than this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437179/traits-as-a-return-value-from-a-function), I would like that the return type of a function to be a trait, the return value being an instance of a type implementing that trait. A simple example:

```
fn myfunction() -> Box<Printable> {
    box TypeB{val: 2} as Box<Printable>
}
```

If I don't explicitly cast into a box of my generic trait, I get:

> error: mismatched types: expected `Box<Printable>` but found
>   `Box<TypeB>` (expected trait Printable but found struct TypeB)

So I wonder:

- If it is the normal way to proceed in Rust to return a trait type
- Why the Rust compiler cannot infer that automatically downcast

Any idea? I am using the current nightly version of the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a trait object like that is the correct way to return a trait, although, if possible, returning a concrete type without a `Box` is more flexible: the callers of that function can box/cast if they need to. If that isn't directly possible, defining and returning an `enum` may work. (Boxing and trait objects should be regarded as somewhat of a last resort: it is often less efficient than other strategies.)

Unfortunately, implicit coercions don't yet infer from return values (they do in other contexts e.g. `foo(box bar)` will coerce that argument to a trait object if required); this will hopefully be fixed, but the explicit cast is required for now.

Comment: Thanks. The idea of my test was to write a factory function (ex: implementing an abstraction layer to a DB).

Comment: @Fabimaru, ah, that does sound something trait objects may be appropriate for.